# Multi-index vs a .number of indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` of about 100k rows, of the format:-

```
ID, Date, Count
1,  11-12-2017,23
1,  12-12-2017,21
2,  11-12-2017,13
2,  12-12-2017,28
3,  11-12-2017,22
3,  12-12-2017,23
```

Within this, I have to process data for a particular date, for all the ID's present. I have now applied index on the ID :-

```
df2 = df.set_index('ID')
df3 = df2[:"123"]
```

Here, will it be better to apply an index on date on df3, or should I have used a multi-index on df itself initially.

So, in the above df, I want to get data for IDs 1,3 for date 11-12-2017

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you having trouble with.

Comment: I could do 2 things here. Have a df3.set_index('Date), or df.set_index(['ID','Date']).  What would be more efficient, having a multi-index on 100k df, or single index on 1k df3.

Comment: If you set the date now, you'll lose the ID index, unless you reset and set again. So the answer would be to set both at the same time.

Comment: Right, so for df3, I don't require the index on ID.

Comment: Then why do you need to set it at all...?

Comment: So, the problem here is that for a date say 11th Dec, I need to get the count for some ID's. So from df2, I would get data corresponding to the ID's, hence the index on ID. Further then, I would get corresponding to 11th Dec, hence the index required on Date.

Comment: You can have both as the index, and then slice accordingly. It isn't hard. With an example, I can write an answer and show you. Can you add some reproducible data example explaining what it is you want to do?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a `MultiIndex` here, rather than setting the index multiple times.

```
df

               Count
ID Date             
1  11-12-2017     23
   12-12-2017     21
2  11-12-2017     13
   12-12-2017     28
3  11-12-2017     22
   12-12-2017     23
```

The advantage of a `MultiIndex` is that you can index slices using a host of convenience functions. For example, the usage of `pd.IndexSlice` is applicable here -

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[[1, 3], '11-12-2017'], :]

               Count
ID Date             
1  11-12-2017     23
3  11-12-2017     22
```

To get counts corresponding to a particular date, slice every `ID` with `:` -

```
df.loc[idx[:, '11-12-2017'], :]

               Count
ID Date             
1  11-12-2017     23
2  11-12-2017     13
3  11-12-2017     22
```

You can also use `df.xs` if you want to get all rows for a particular value at the 0th level, for example -

```
df.xs(1)

            Count
Date             
11-12-2017     23
12-12-2017     21
```

Which gives you all rows for `ID` of `1`.